# how do I declare and initialize an array of bytes in C++

Tags: c++, byte, c++20, literals, uniform-initialization

Is this really the best way to declare a byte (or array of bytes)?

```
static constexpr byte kGuard1_[] = {
            byte{0x45}, byte{0x23}, byte{0x12}, byte{0x56}, byte{0x99}, byte{0x76}, byte{0x12}, byte{0x55},
        };
```

why isn't there some suffix (like b) that you can use to directly mark the number as a byte? Or is the problem just with my use of uniform initialization?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't say if this is *better* but it's *different* since you won't have to repeat `byte` for every element:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <utility>

template <class T, class... Args>
constexpr auto mkarr(Args&&... args) {
    return std::array{static_cast<T>(std::forward<Args>(args))...};
}

static constexpr auto kGuard1 = mkarr<std::byte>(0x45, 0x23, 0x12, 0x56,
                                                 0x99, 0x76, 0x12, 0x55);
```

Note that it uses a `std::array<std::byte, 8>` instead of a `std::byte[8]`.

---

> why isn't there some suffix (like b) that you can use to directly mark the number as a byte?

I can't say, but if you want you can define your own user-defined literal that could be used with C arrays.

```cpp
constexpr std::byte operator""_B(unsigned long long x) {
    // note: no space between "" and _B above
    return static_cast<std::byte>(x); 
}

static constexpr std::byte kGuard1[]{0x45_B, 0x23_B, 0x12_B, 0x56_B,
                                     0x99_B, 0x76_B, 0x12_B, 0x55_B};
```

> Or is the problem just with my use of uniform initialization?

No, it's just that there is no implicit conversion to `std::byte`.

Comment: Leaning towards adding the operator""_B thing, but doesn't work well cuz - in what namespace do I add it? The right answer is std, but thats illegal. And the mkarr() thing, is also terrible. Declaring arrays of bytes is not unusual. I could add a library routine mkarray, but seems to have very few use cases but this, and overkill for this one case. Sigh, but thank you!

Comment: note in case not clear, the issue about namespaces with operator""_B, is that it only applies if you have done 'using' of that namespace.

Comment: @lewis The note I made was to make that explicit. No infringement on the standard library.

Comment: Not sure what your comment about 'the note i made'. If you are referring to the but about explicit conversions, that's why I said uniform initialization could be the problem (since then no requirement about implicit conversions). Anyhow - leaning towards your _B approach. I just wish this was in the standard library so I didn't need to do a using namespace 'some_utilities' to be able to use it.

Comment: The note was about `no space between "" and _B above`.  About _"mkarr() thing, is also terrible"_ - I can't agree. There will be no copies or moves so it's just like your original initialization and if you do this kind of init more than once in your code, then I'd say it's spot on. One could argue that initializing a bunch of bits with specific values makes the bunch of bits a lot more like `uint8_t`s though.

Comment: About _" in what namespace do I add it?"_ I'd say the narrowest one + a sub namespace with something called `literals` in it to follow the standard library way of doing it so that people using your literal a lot can opt it in.

Comment: @lewis Btw, did I answer your original question or was an answer to _"why isn't there some suffix (like b) that you can use to directly mark the number as a byte?"_ required? I did a search for it but could not find a proposal to add such a literal to the standard library.

Comment: You didn't answer it perfectly or completely (I was hoping to hear this was going to be fixed in the std library, or a reason why it didn't make sense to add, or another coding pattern that makes this work simply and naturally).

Comment: BUT - thats asking too much ;-) For now I take the answer to be use _b operator"" stuff in your own namespace, and most other people (at least in the standards process) dont care enough about this particular issue. Which makes some sense.

Comment: @lewis :-) Sometimes people (me included) get surprised that some parts seems to be missing from the standard library. Often the answer is _"noone proposed it_" :-)

Comment: The trouble is - there is a high bar for 'proposing' a change. I almost didn't bother posting to stackoverflow. Let alone writing a 10 page legalese document, and thinking out all the wording magic needed for an official proposal.

Comment: @lewis I agree that it does seem tough to get something in. A smoother way may be to suggest it to `boost` and if accepted into `boost`, it can live there for some time (years) and perhaps then be picked up by happy users of the idea. I have one minor idea that would fit nicely into the standard library that I've been thinking about venting with `boost` but even that takes some effort :-)

Comment: One of my hobby projects is to create my own library, which I've added this too.          https://github.com/SophistSolutions/Stroika/blob/e77df1eb378bb4b6ade05ac051b83884b4ac4e7f/Library/Sources/Stroika/Foundation/Memory/Common.h#L128

Comment: @lewis Cool! I've started similar things but nowadays I mainly only bother to be that organized at work :)